# › vs - vs | , which title separator is suggested for the best Google SEO practice?

Tags: seo, title

Try to compare these 3 titles:

1. What Is My IP Address - See Your Public Address
2. What Is My IP Address › See Your Public Address
3. What Is My IP Address | See Your Public Address

Which one is best for Google SEO?

Thanks,

Comment: Similar question, useful answers: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71140/how-title-structure-and-separators-affect-seo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, it mostly doesn't matter what you use as a separator. Literature on this is scant, though I think [this is a good article](https://northward.io/articles/title-separator-symbols). Just don't use any crazy characters, as results may display in unexpected ways and might even look spammy. (More on that in [this thread from this very forum](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71140/how-title-structure-and-separators-affect-seo).)

Of the three options you listed, I don't see `>` much, and I've never used it myself. The symbol implies either movement to the right or a greater-than comparison, so I'd stay away from this vague symbol as a separator. (The more obvious the better, right?)

Either the pipe or the hyphen are fine, and really up to you. I have always used both. That is, I prefer to use the pipe to separate the site name from the page title, and the hyphen as a separator within the page title, if applicable:

```
<title>Blog Entries Section | Site Name</title>

<title>Blog Entries Section - page 2 | Site Name</title>
```

I find this to be visually elegant for the user.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Actually I didn't put a `>` but a `›`

Comment: Gotcha, @AGamePlayer - thanks for the correction. That looks better, visually, but the same comments apply.

Comment: Thanks, Henry. Very insightful comments and I think `-` is better now. Indeed rarely `›` is used in titles. However, in the search results, there are cases that they've been used.

Comment: True, @AGamePlayer - I've recently seen bullets used as dividers as well. I stick to the conservative guidelines, given that we pretty much know how they'll be displayed. But do feel free to experiment; if the result is weird, you can always change it, and the results often update almost instantly.

Comment: "bullet"? do you mean this `•`?

Comment: Correct. I recently saw a colleague use this. It displayed properly in the browser. I don't use them, but again, feel free to experiment, as long as the search results look right to you.